# Foreach array with different values

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

Need little help, i get always stupid errors, when i try to do this, i want to foreach array, and inside that do a for loop, is this possible?
Here is my code

```
$image = new SimpleImage();
$slike=array($_FILES['slika1']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['slika2']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['slika3']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['slika4']['tmp_name']);

$koliko = count($slike);

foreach ($slike as $slika) {

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $koliko; $i++)
    {
        $slicica="../images/usluge/".mysql_insert_id()."-".$i.".jpg";
        $image->load($slika);
        $image->resizeToWidth(800);
        $image->save($slicica);
    }
}
```

I want to get new pictures with this name, example.If last id was 2 i want to get this filenames etc

- 2-1.jpg
- 2-2.jpg
- 2-3.jpg
- 2-4.jpg

Still with my code i dont get correct values :(
Or maybe there is easy way to do that :)

Comment: What are these "stupid errors" you are getting? And what values are you currently getting?

Comment: I get no erorrs, but i got only one picture that is the same, last picture, that is same, but got names 2-1.jpg, 2-2.jpg, 2-3.jpg, 2-4.jpg. Like all previous pictures are overwrite :(

Comment: mysql_insert_id() will return the same value for you on each iteration of the loop, unless you're doing an insert on each iteration.

Comment: I want to have mysql_insert_id() in filename, that is not a problem, the problem goes when i want to add -1 , -2, -3 etc

Comment: What platform you are using Linux ?

Comment: Please try my code and you shall see what you will get :(

Comment: Yes, Linux, but i dont know that is a issuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to replace your following line:

```
$image->load($slika);
```

for this one:

```
$image->load($slike[$i-1]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated code in my answer it had an index error, try new code again..

Comment: Nelson, you are the king, this is the best solution, you are the best. Works like a charm, txanks !

Comment: Can you help me a little more, i have $slike array, how to look there is empty value and to unset?

Comment: Don't know exactly what you want.. for unsetting array items you have `unset()` and to check empty `is_empty()`..

Answer (score 0):

you probably have a problem in you foreach  as if we do a var_dump on an array we will see the following :

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "test1" [1]=> string(4) "tes2" [2]=> string(5) "test3" }
```

so you need to change it to :

```
foreach ($slike as $key => $slika) {
```

you can also use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to achieve what you are trying to do and use linux command [convert](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/) :

```
foreach ($slike as $key => $slika) {

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $koliko; $i++)
    {
        $slicica="../images/usluge/".mysql_insert_id()."-".$i.".jpg";
        if(move_uploaded_file(slika,slicica)){ 
            exec("convert $slicica -resize 200 $slicica");
        }else{die('problem loading the file');}

    }
}
```

Comment: @take I saw this : `$_FILES['slika1']['tmp_name']` that is why I proposed using `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: Yes I saw it to late, thats why I removed my comment. sorry.

Comment: @user2266992 try debugging your variables, it does not hurt to add some `var_dump($variables)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=1;
// insert into mysql table..
// [...]
$mysqlId = mysql_insert_id();
foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value) {

    $slicica="../images/usluge/".$mysqlId."-".$i.".jpg";
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$key]["tmp_name"],slicica)){ 
        $image->load($slicica);
        $image->resizeToWidth(800);
        $image->save($slicica);
    }
    else {
        // error handling
    }
    $i++;
}
```